# Expression analysis in textbox qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I have data like this in a sheet:

```
products obtained   total
p1           1200   10000
p2           1000   20000
p3            200   30000
p1           1400   10000
p2           1200   20000
p3            600   30000
```

If I get the sum of products then p1 shows **2400 p2=2400 and p3=800**

So I get 2400 top value against twp products ..

I want to get top values in textbox like this:

```
p1 (2400/10000)  p2 (2400/20000)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: check out my answer below

Answer (score 0):

example for p1:

```
='p1 ('&sum({<products={'p1'}>} obtained)&'/'&only{<products={'p1'}>} total)&')'
```

might want to use `avg` instead of `only` if the `total` can change